# Question on balancing different light sources- God rays

Tags: lighting, volumetrics

I am making this google logo ball of sorts. I want it to have volumetric lighting emphasising the geometry like in the picture. However I don´t want it to have too much light hitting the floor.

I know there is a camera ray node - you can choose what the camera picks up depending on how many bounces it has et.c but am not sure if I could use it. How would you do to reduce the floor lighting and keep the volumetrics strong?

Also my volumetric cube makes everything grey and messes up the other lights in the scene. How would you go around it?   [image]